# Intercom with Magento 2.3.3 ver problem

Tags: magento2, php, module, magento2.3

we get the below error when we install **Intercom** on Magento 2.3.3 ver problem

https://i.ibb.co/qxSbXSX/2019-12-06-124841.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run command like..

```
composer config repositories.compactcode-base git git@github.com:CompactCodeEU/base.git && composer config repositories.compactcode-intercom git git@github.com:CompactCodeEU/intercom.git

composer require "compactcode/intercom:dev-master"

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Follow this [link](https://github.com/CompactCodeEU/intercom#composer-install-instructions)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: not work composer config repositories.compactcode-base git git@github.com:CompactCodeEU/base.git && composer config repositories.compactcode-intercom git git@github.com:CompactCodeEU/intercom.git


get "Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details"

Comment: @MuhammedOmar, Please try 2nd and 3rd command once and check.

Comment: working fine https://github.com/CompactCodeEU/intercom

Comment: Great! Thank you! :)